# If I transfer files from a school computer to my own will the school have access to my computer?

Tags: usb

I have some files I want from my school computer to my own computer and I want to know if I do will the school have access to my computer (Using a usb ofc) my school computer also has restrictions and i am wondering that, if I transfer a file (like an image, png etc) if the restrictions will be added to my personal computer

Answer (score 2):

If you transfer files then it shouldn't, in and of itself, give your school access to your personal computer. The previous statement is mostly for non-executable files. When it comes to executables, you have to check their digital signature and the files' origins. Even executables won't give them access, most of the time. BUT, I remember, once, when I was in middle school, I was curious about DeepFreeze and I executed my school's customized DeepFreeze installer on my personal computer. I ended up having to get a teacher to come to my home and disable it, because I didn't have the password to do it myself.
Nevertheless, executables can also harbor malware, so you should be aware of that, too. Executables, in Windows, end in .exe, .vbs, etc.

Comment: So if I transfer a folder with photos and txt files the school does not get access to my computer

Comment: @lilshine No, they won't.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

No. Copying files to your computer does not give anyone any access to your computer. Neither any technical restrictions will be propagated to your computer. If there are any legal restrictions, they can still be applicable, but it is off topic on Security SE.

There are basically two scenarios for somebody to get access to your computer (not considering exploits of bugs in OS or some software):

- Active access: Make sure your provider does not block incoming requests. Install SSH, RDP or similar service. Give credentials to somebody who wants to access your computer. Then this party can access your computer whenever they want.
- Passive access: You install a client that enables remote access like LogMeIn or TeamViewer. For somebody to get access you have always to initiate an access session. Then you invite the other party to access your computer. The other party cannot get access without you first initiating a remote access session.